# Need advice on getting access token with multiple Task in Microsoft.Graph

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I use [Microsoft.Graph](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Graph) to make app only calls against Azure AD.
In a nutshell, my code is the following (C# .NET 4.5):

```
Task userQueryTask = Task.Run(async () =>
{
    IGraphServiceUsersCollectionPage users = await connection.GraphService.Users.Request().Select(userSelect).Filter(userFilter).GetAsync();
}, cts.Token);

Task groupQueryTask = Task.Run(async () =>
{
    IGraphServiceGroupsCollectionPage groups = await connection.GraphService.Groups.Request().Select(groupSelect).Filter(groupFilter).GetAsync();
}, cts.Token);

Task.WaitAll(new Task[2] { userQueryTask, groupQueryTask }, Constants.timeout, cts.Token);
```

Here are my questions:

- Is it a good practice to use the same GraphServiceClient object in 2 tasks running in parallel?
- I noticed that the first time this code runs, both tasks call https://login.microsoftonline.com/myDomain.onMicrosoft.com/oauth2/token to get an access token, and then they query Azure AD through https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/. Should I try to improve this and avoid that both tasks get an access token?
- Side question: do I need to do anything to handle the refresh of the access token?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it a good practice to use the same GraphServiceClient object in 2 tasks running in parallel?

As [Robert Anderson](https://github.com/shiftylogic) answered about [Recommended lifetime for a GraphServiceClient instance](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/issues/58):

> The Graph client object is thread-safe and re-entrant. It is a container containing configuration, providers, and helpers for constructing request objects via a builder pattern.

Since the `GraphServiceClient` is thread-safe, you could re-use the same instance across multiple threads. AFAIK, If you create a lot of `HttpClient` instances to access the related Graph APIs, you also may need to re-use a set of instances, or you may encounter the memory-leak issue.

> Should I try to improve this and avoid that both tasks get an access token?

Per my experience, you'd better use the same access_token instead of generating token for each task. Also, you could create a `TokenHelper` class to cache the acquired access_token and record the expire time. Under the `GetTokenAsync` method, you need to validate the current access_token (if null, then get a new token; if the token would be expired soon, then acquire a new token again).

```
var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(
            "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0",
            new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(
                async (requestMessage) =>
                {
                    var token = await TokenHelper.GetTokenAsync();
                    requestMessage.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", token);
                }));
```

**Note:** The `TokenHelper.GetTokenAsync` method may needs to be thread-safe.